# Is there a way to display the protocol in the address bar?

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome, the protocol is hidden for some reason.  This affects copy/paste from the address bar into an email or some other document.  For example, let's say I am at this URL:

`subdomain.domain.com/myvitualdir/customerprofile.aspx?id=18272`

If I just want to copy `subdomain.domain.com/myvitualdir/myvitualdir`, it won't actually copy the HTTP part.

**Update**:  I just figured out what causes this "quirk" to occur.  Let's say you have `www.whatever.com/myvd` in your browser history.  If you start typing `whatever` in the address bar, Chrome will start auto-completing matching URLs for you.  While still in the auto-complete stage (ie, not actually browsing to the URL), attempting to copy the URL will not include the protocol.  It seems intermittent, though, because sometimes it copies the protocol and other times it doesn't.

Comment: [This is a list of all command line arguments](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). So far I found _none_ to enable the protocol.

Comment: Your Chrome is weird. Even though the protocol is invisible, Chrome has _always_ auto-added it when copying...

Comment: To copy the protocol part, you have to copy the whole url, not just a part of it. If you need to edit the url, copy/paste the whole thing and edit after you paste it.

Comment: @grawity As Jakke commented, you have to copy the whole URL and then edit it after you paste it.  However, I want to copy only part of the URL (eg, from the middle to the beginning).  When you do that, the protocol doesn't copy and it's a bit of an annoyance.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: For reference, what Chrome version are you currently using?

Comment: @and31415 35.0.1916.153 m

Comment: Do you get the same issue with websites that use the HTTPS or FTP protocols?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: When you copy from the middle, it still does the same for me, as long as I select at least the whole domain (e.g. `superuser.com/ques` still gets the scheme prefix).

Comment: I just wish I could always see the protocol at a glance. It takes too long to discern whether I'm on http or https etc.

Answer (score 3):

Currently and unfortunately, the is no way to display the protocol in the address bar in Chrome. You have to use another browser.